# 2-d geometric Brownian motion hitting time distribution

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am trying to solve following problem: Given two independent geometric Brownian motions

$\frac{d x_t}{x_t}=\mu_x dt + \sigma_x dw_t^x$

and

$\frac{d y_t}{y_t}=\mu_y dt + \sigma_y dW_t^y$

and some initial point $(x_0, y_0)$ to the right of the line $y=\phi_0 + \phi_1 x$

($y_0 < \phi_0 + \phi_1 x_0)$

I want to know what the distribution of the time it takes to hit the line is.

I think I know how to solve it if they are Brownian motions: I apply Bayes' rule to compute the probability of hitting the line after and before the hitting time, and that helps. But I need the symmetry of the Brownian motion at some point which I don't have in the GBM.

Any help on how to get started is very helpful.